# How to change color of a PHP string in Notepad++?

Tags: php, notepad++

Example:

```
  $string[34] = 'test';
```

I would like test to be black-colored or at least #333. Current one is light gray and not very visible.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4):

In the Style Configurator under Settings, select php as the language and select 'SIMPLESTRING', then change the style to your liking.

[image: Example]